# 404 on Election Page URL

Tags: bug

There are several "**Election**" links on the badges page which are currently throwing 404 errors:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/badges

Two of the links are noted in the image below. There may be others:

[image: Problems links noted in this image]

Comment: Interesting catch. Of course there is no /election page before the first election happens, but we should have either a default landing page or remove the hard link in the badge description. Reported.

Comment: Thank you Robert. What are elections exactly? When do those happen?

Comment: @MediaGirl They are how moderators are chosen (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/election)). I read somewhere that for new/beta sites they appoint provisional moderators until a site is large enough to sustain elections ([link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)).

Comment: Might take us awhile to get to elections. Thank you for that link!